# RubyMine（もしくはJetBrains製品）でES6のブレイクポイントが機能しない

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gulp, npm, rubymine

おそらく
https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5526866

John Hunter氏の

> when I start debugging, no breakpoints are ever hit (it does open up the page in chrome and I get the message ''JetBrains IDE Support is debugging this tab). I have set breakpoints in my ES6 js files and the generated js files. I feel like I am missing something, but I don't know what.

の発言と同じ現象が起こっているようです。

その後の発言を見ると、

`gulp.src` を触るとうまくいったよ的な展開になっている感じがしますが、

プロジェクト内で、
`gulp.src(['plugin/**/*.es6'])`で検索してもヒットしませんし、
`gulp.src`で検索すると、`node_modules`の中に数件ヒットしますが、いったいどこをいじればよいのでしょうか？（というか`node_modules`の中をいじくるものなのでしょうか...）

どなたかES6のブレイクポイントが上手く動いた方はいませんか？

Answer (score 1):

引用されているやり取りを読みましたが、`gulp.src` のことには特に触れられていないと思います。

挙がっている話としては、

- [規格に沿った](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit?hl=en_US) sourcemap が生成され、それが .js ファイルから `//@sourceMappingURL` で正しく関連付けられていることが必要
- WebStorm の babel file watcher を使えば期待通りにブレークポイントが機能したが、 babel-gulp を使うとブレークポイントが機能しなかった。最終的には、 gulp-sourcemaps が生成した .js.map ファイルに間違った `sourceRoot` が出力されていたようで、正しい値を指定したら動くようになった（これが最後に載っている gulpfile）

というところでしょうか。

Mark氏の書かれた二つの gulpfile を比べると、 `includeContent` の指定も増えているのが気になりますが・・・とりあえず上記二点を確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。